# How to configure VS 2010 to make a DLL which utilizes other DLLs

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, dll, ffmpeg

My Visual Studio 2010 project target is a DLL.   This particular DLL is for use with some video analytics.   The DLL I am building will connect to RTSP cameras and provide video to the analytics engine.   The interfaces my DLL must provide are well documented by the analytics engine.

I have configured my VS project to have a target of a DLL.   It compiles my code just fine.   However, I am utilizing ffmpeg to assist with some RTSP stuff and to conversion of video frames to the format needed by the analytics engine.   I have the headers for ffmpeg and can compile just fine against it.   However, when my DLL goes to link, all the functions from ffmpeg are listed as unresolved external symbols.

I have the libraries (avcodec, avutil, etc) listed as additional linker dependencies (the .lib versions obviously) and when I turn on verbose mode, I can see that it picked up the additional linker directory path I specified and found the ffmpeg files in their directory.   However, it doesn't seem to want to link them.

If my make my project a static library instead of a DLL, everything links just fine.   However, I need generate a DLL.    So, how do I configure VS2010 to pull in these ffmpeg DLLs (or libs) and complete the link and generated my DLL.

Extra Credit, is there a way to pull the DLLs in together so I only need to deploy my single DLL instead of having to install all the ffmpeg DLLs in addition to the one I wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had a number of issues.   To get this going, I needed to alter my #include statements as follows :

```
extern "C"
{
#include "include\libavcodec\avcodec.h"
#include "include\libavformat\avformat.h"
#include "include\libavformat\avio.h"
#include "include\libswscale\swscale.h"
#include "include\libavutil\dict.h"
#include "include\libavutil\frame.h"
}
```

I then had two options to include the DLLs.   The first involved adding a line into code for each DLL I needed to load.   As follows :

```
#pragma comment(lib, "..\\..\\..\\..\\contrib\\ffmpeg-latest\\lib\\avformat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "..\\..\\..\\..\\contrib\\ffmpeg-latest\\lib\\swscale.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "..\\..\\..\\..\\contrib\\ffmpeg-latest\\lib\\avutil.lib")
```

Alternately, I was able to list the lib directly as an Additional Dependency in the linker tab.   Such as : "..\..\..\..\contrib\ffmpeg-latest\lib\avcodec.lib"

I have not attempted to run with this yet, but based on what I've read, it will only work if I provide the DLLs at run-time.   I haven't a clue how to get it to include the DLLs with my DLL into one large DLL.

I also had downloaded 64 bit libraries and was compiling 32 bit.   I'm not sure if that was going to mess things up or not but I did switch so they were consistent.